# Flag duplicates with highest value - Excel

Tags: arrays, excel, duplicates, conditional-statements

I have a column of IDs (A) and a column of scores (B).

For some IDs there are duplicates.

I'm looking to flag the instance of each ID with the highest score.

Currently I have this:

```
{=IF(MAX(IF(A:A=A2,B:B,""))=B2,"Yes","No")}
```

It works, but excel crashes when I try and run it for all 10,000 rows.

New ideas or how to streamline my current formula would be appreciated!

Thanks.

Comment: That is because the Array formula calculates exponentially.  To get around that you will need to sort your data first on A and Then B, then you can use a standard formula to do the check.  Or you will need vba.

Comment: Also, try limiting the full column references to only those of the data set, that **MAY** allow it to calculate.  Though with 10,000 rows I would use vba.